# Sending Multiple rows in single mail using azure logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want to send multiple rows of a single SQL query in single mail using Azure logic apps. I tried but I am getting mail for each row. Is there any way to achieve this? Help me out to find a solution.

Example query:

```
Select * from TestTable; --it has 5 rows for example.
```

So, I want to send these 5 rows in a single mail using azure logic apps. If we can send this in excel file it would be even better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please share what you have tried before ? I guess you can create an email and add an attachment. you just convert your select result to csv and add it as an attachment ??

Comment: Hi, Joey Cai answered what I was looking for. Pls. Refer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to send these 5 rows in a single mail using azure logic apps.

You could use Expression with `body('Execute_a_SQL_query')?['resultsets']?['Table1']` in email `body` which will list the query result in single email.

Designer:

[image]

Output:

[image]

> If we can send this in excel file it would be even better.

If you want to send the query result as a excel file and send email, you could add a **Create CSV table** connector, and **add the file as attachment** when sending email.

Designer:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, this is what the requirements I was searching for. I'll try it and let you know if it works for me or not.

Comment: Hey Joey Cai , It is working fine . Thank you so much.

Comment: @Selvi.P, glad to help you. If it solve your problem, you could mark it as answer to  close the problem.

Comment: Can't we send file in Excel ? pls. help

Comment: It seems that you could not send the whole excel file in email sending.